# Suggested JSON structure for Exceptions?

Tags: json, rest, exception

Out of curiosity, are there any popular standards for returning server side exceptions (and corresponding details) in an API that returns JSON? The exceptions could be anything from uncaught exceptions in the code or thrown exceptions put in place by the developer.

Currently I'm setting the HTTP Status Code according to their [Wiki definitions'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

My JSON response would look something like this:

```
HTTP Code: 401

{'error': 'Authentication required.', 'message': 'You must be authenticated to perform that action.'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at JSON-RPC (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC).

In case of success, the response is like this:

```
{
    "result": ...(returned data)...
    ...
}
```

and in case of error, the response is like that:

```
{
    "error": ...(error details)...
    ...
}
```

When the error occured, "error" property must be present and "result" property must not be returned. In case there was no error, "error" property must not be set. This way you can distinguish errors from successful responses based solely on the content of the response, without the need to check the headers (like response codes).

Answer (score 1):

The standard structure of native ECMAScript error objects is:

```
{
    name: ...,
    message: ...
}
```

where "name" is the type of the error (the name of the corresponding constructor, like "Error", "SyntaxError", etc.). In your example, you could use the name "AuthentificationError", for instance.

Comment: That is correct, but errors in JavaScript are distinguishable from eg. arrays, whereas JSON objects representing errors are not distinguishable from objects representing eg. user data. I believe you should nest your object within "error" property of the root object. This way you can distinguish error from successful data not only based on HTTP code.

Comment: @Tadeck I don't think that's necessary, since the OP is setting 4xx status codes when sending errors to the client. The status code is available as the `.status` property of the response object.

Comment: Great comment @Tadeck. So you would suggest something like {'error': {'name': '...', 'message': '...'}} ?

Comment: @used2could: Yes, I would suggest adding some solution similar to JSON-RPC (see my answer), if you need it. However, Sime Vidas is right about status codes - they should also reflect if there are any errors or not. Anyway, in REST you should use status codes to full extent (which does not limit you in setting error responses' contents in the way you find more suitable).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do the same.
As we know that Web servers allow us to create **custom error pages for HTTP errors**, in those custom error pages you have to serve the JSON reply

Example:
Add the following to your WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<error-page>  
       <error-code>401</error-code>  
         <location>/autherror.jsp</location>  
</error-page>
```

In the autherror.jsp file code the required logic to accomplish your needed JSON reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try being a bit more verbose regarding the error  you are sending. This structure  has been suggested in some places to give sufficient information both for users and developer using your API

```
"error":{
       "code":"410",
       "long":"410001",
       "message":"cannot connect to DB",
       "developer":"Connection to the DB was unsuccessful due to ...",
       "documentation": "mysite.com/help/errors/..."
   }
```

1. Return the correct HTTP  code for error.  It  is  bad practice to return code 200 with error.
2. Extend the code  with your own error IDs
3. Provide short message that roughly outlines the cause  of the error. Consider adding more detailed message for the developers. Have in mind that API error messages are 99.9% of the time read by developers so make them happy by providing technical details (within reason) so that they can resolve ASAP.
4. In case you keep public documentation about your api and error codes, simply add the url.